# How to write the logged in user id in Plotalot queries?

Tags: mysql, user, session

I am trying to use plotalot to graph user results.  The program only uses mysql queries to pull data.  How can I pull session specific user data with a mysql query?  Normal Joomla session variables are not available to use.  I've tried many versions of this, but session variables are not set?

```
SELECT Calcd_Results
FROM user_results
WHERE user_id = $_SESSION["user_id"]
```

Comment: yes, @James actually just answered the question. The sub-answer would be: 'please read the documentation of the extension you use'. :)

Comment: since, exceptionally, Plotalot has a pretty impressive documentation (more than 70 pages). From page 63. (advance techniques) it gives great examples on advanced usage, incuding the example what @James just gave above.

Comment: Thank you @jamesgarrett and Zollie  - I read through the first 50 pages but didn't get to 70 since this documentation gave lots of examples but very little about how the system actually works.  I even searches some terms that didn't yield anything and reviewed the other 13 page developer guide.  Seemed to reinforce the idea to me that it would not do the function I wanted.  My bad.  Thats why I asked.

Comment: My apologies for there being two questions too.  Thanks for the help.

Comment: @BabyCode123 - no problem at all, it takes a good amount of time for anybody to get familiar with an extension like that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Plotalot includes various variables that can be used in sql queries, eg.

```
%%J_USER_ID%%
```

is the currently logged in user_id. The [Plotalot User Documentation Available as PDF here](https://www.lesarbresdesign.info/extensions/plotalot/downloads)